# the computer demonstrated the app?

Tags: semantic-roles

Does "The computer demonstrated the app" sound wrong or otherwise unnatural?
If so, why?

I'd think the sentence describes an automatic process whereby the computer was programmed to demonstrate the app. Is that the only natural context in which it could be found?

I'd appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

This is a case where the passive comes in handy:

> The app was demonstrated on the computer.

Your sentence sounds unnatural because a native speaker would typically use the passive here.

Comment: What is it about the OP sentence that makes you think it is unnatural?

Comment: My answer directly addresses the question in your comment.

Comment: How about "The computer played the songs in succession"? Is it unnatural as well?

Comment: If your focus is on what the computer is doing, then it's fine to make it the subject and use the active voice. In the original question, you seemed to imply that you did not like the implication of an "automatic process"; hence my recommendation of the passive there with "on the computer".

Comment: I see. So you agree it's possible to use the sentence in the OP if it describes an automatic process.

Comment: When you make "the computer" the subject of the verb, you're describing a machine doing something.  If that is your intention, go with it.  If your focus is on the app being demonstrated, make "the app" the subject.